# The object is not saved in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

this is a piece of code from method where is loading some elements via TFHpple:

```
// kvota1Niz, KvotaxNiz and Kvota2Niz are result arrays from TFHpple parser
NSArray *kvota1Niz = [kvoteParser searchWithXPathQuery:kvota1XpathUpit];
NSArray *kvotaxNiz = [kvoteParser searchWithXPathQuery:kvotaxXpathUpit];
NSArray *kvota2Niz = [kvoteParser searchWithXPathQuery:kvota2XpathUpit];
NSMutableArray *kvote1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableArray *kvotex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableArray *kvote2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableArray *privremeniArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in kvota1Niz)
{
    Par *trenutnaKvota1 =  [[Par alloc] init];
    [kvote1 addObject:trenutnaKvota1];
    trenutnaKvota.kvota1 = [[element firstChild] content];
}
for (TFHppleElement *element in kvotaxNiz)
{
    Par *trenutnaKvotax =  [[Par alloc] init];

    if ([_sekvencaLogoa objectAtIndex: [kvotaxNiz indexOfObject:element]] == @"2")
    {
        [privremeniArray addObject:trenutnaKvotaX]
    }
    else
    {
        [kvotex addObject:trenutnaKvotax];
    }
    trenutnaKvota.kvotax = [[element firstChild] content];
}
for (TFHppleElement *element in kvota2Niz)
{
    Par *trenutnaKvota2 =  [[Par alloc] init];
    if ([_sekvencaLogoa objectAtIndex: [kvota2Niz indexOfObject:element]] == @"2")
    {
        [kvote2 addObject:[privremeniArray objectAtIndex:k]];
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        [kvote2 addObject:trenutnaKvota2];
    }
    trenutnaKvota.kvota2 = [[element firstChild] content];
}
kvota1 = _kvota1;
kvotax = _kvotax;
kvota2 = _kvota2;
```

The problem is in `for(TFHppleElement *element in kvota2Niz)` where `[privremeniArray objectAtIndex:k]` is not saved in the `kvote2` array. The program enters the for loop, as I `NSLogged` the value `k`.
`kvota2` is an `NSString` instance variable of the `Par` class.
`_sekvencaLogoa` is an array containing the strings `"2"` and `"3"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does not work? Adding an object to the array? Where are the log statements?

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct string comparsion

```
 if ([_sekvencaLogoa objectAtIndex: [kvota2Niz indexOfObject:element]] == @"2")
        {
            [kvote2 addObject:[privremeniArray objectAtIndex:k]];
            k++;
        }
```

Use this:

```
 if ([[_sekvencaLogoa objectAtIndex: [kvota2Niz indexOfObject:element]] isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {
            [kvote2 addObject:[privremeniArray objectAtIndex:k]];
            k++;
        }
```

Comment: NeverBe, I tried your suggestion, but the same thing. int k is incremented, so the comparision syntax is ok. There must be 20 Par objects in kvote2 array, but there are only 17, and those 17 are from [kvote2 addObject:trenutnaKvota2]; 3 object have to be added by [kvote2 addObject:[privremeniArray objectAtIndex:k]];

Really weird :(